# Accessing nested arrays through ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to iterate through this array using ng-repeat?

```
{
    "classess": [
        "Upper sixth form",
        "Lower sixth form"
        {
            "group": "Year 11",
            "students": [
                "rob",
                "lisa",
                "natalie",
                "greg"
            ]
        },
        {
            "group": "Year 10",
            "students": [
                "tom",
                "ross",
                "james",
                "nicola"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Ideally it would be great to format it like this:

```
- Upper sixth form
- Lower sixth form
- Year 11
    - rob
    - lisa
    - natalie
    - greg
- Year 10
    - tom
    - ross
    - james
    -nicola
```

I can't change the way the data appears, is this something that can be done through ng-repeat or would this have to be filtered in the controller?

Edit:
This is what my current HTML looks like

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="class in classes">
        {{ class }}
        <ul ng-if="class.group">
            <h6>{{ class.group }}</h6>
            <li ng-repeat="student in class.students">
                {{student}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but this is what it produces:

```
- Upper sixth form
- Lower sixth form
- {"group":"Year 11","ingredients":["rob","lisa","natalie","greg"]}
    - Year 11

        rob
        lisa
        natalie
        greg

- {"group":"Year 10","ingredients":["tom","ross","james","nicola"]}
    - Year 10

        tom
        ross
        james
        nicola
```

Comment: @code I've added the current html and output it produces

Comment: @code if i do that then 'Upper sixth form' and 'Lower sixth form' don't appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try following HTML to keep it compact and readable, without adding any HTML elements which don't actually have a purpose, e.g. for styling (`div` in your example):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="class in classes">
        {{class.group ? class.group : class}}
        <ul ng-if="class.group">
            <li ng-repeat="student in class.students">
                {{student}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using ng-repeat**

You can use ng-repeat if you have a grasp of loops. Your html will look like this (assuming you have correctly added angular and your controller etc)

```
<div ng-repeat="class in classes">
    {{class.group}}
    <div ng-repeat="student in class">
        <p>{{student}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Possibly will need some tweaking, I could do it with a JSFiddle but this should give you some idea of how to get the list you want.

Comment: but "Upper sixth form" and other doesn't appear with class.group only

Comment: yeah sorry it should just be `{{class}}`. I think that your data structure could be better. But I'd need a fiddle to get an exact result.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the desired output through this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="class in classes">
        <div ng-if="!class.group">
            {{ class }}
        </div>
        <div ng-if="class.group">
            {{ class.group }}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="student in class.students">
                    {{student}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok. You could to try the @PzYon code, it's very clean too. And you can mark your answer as correct. (and others, of course, if you want)